# mysql loop query average python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

This is what I am currently doing but it is not fast...

get latest timestamp and subtract an hr. get average of all the data that lies within this hour. Then do this for a 24 hr period, and eventually longer. I am currently doing it with 24 queries but I was wondering if there was a better way in mysql to do this in a single query. If I run this as 24 queries in python it takes about 16 seconds to finish. I also tried doing semicolon separated multistatements but this only gave me about 2X speed. I was hoping to get it done much quicker as I will eventually do this many times. Here is the python code for this query...

```
db_connection = pymysql.connect(myStuffGoesHere)
count = 24
try:
    with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # first get current server time and subtract 1 day from it
        sql_current = "SELECT now()"
        cursor.execute(sql_current)
        current_time = cursor.fetchall()
        current_time = current_time[0]['now()']
        current_string_time = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        previous_times = []
        real_data = []
        previous_time = current_time
        for i in range(count):
            
            previous_time -= timedelta(days=1)
            previous_string_time = previous_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            previous_times.append(previous_string_time)
          
        for i in range(count):
            sql_data = "SELECT AVG(value) FROM `000027` WHERE time<'" + current_string_time + "' AND time>'" + previous_times[i] + "'"
                
            print(sql_data)
            cursor.execute(sql_data)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in data:
                real_data.append(int(row['AVG(value)']))
            

except Exception as e:
    print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this in one query.

```
SELECT HOUR(time) AS hour, AVG(value) AS average
  FROM `000027`
  WHERE time BETWEEN {start-of-day} and {end-of-day}
  GROUP BY HOUR(time)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This runs much much faster. Thank you.

Comment: What if I wanted to do this for a week or month worth instead of 1 day. I don't think this query can be adjusted to work anymore. Can it?

Comment: You should really look at the Mysql documentation.  I'm not making this up.  Of course you can do it.  You can say GROUP BY MONTH(time) or GROUP BY WEEK(time).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I still need it grouped by Hour(time) but I need more than 24 hours. This only gives 24 valid outputs regardless of timerange.

Comment: `GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM time)`.  Really, seriouisly, go read the "date and time functions" chapter of the Mysql documentation and experiment with it.  There are dozens of functions.

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks for this. It helped a lot.